Why the "gce-workload-cert-refresh.service" uses high CPU periodically on GCP
I recently created a new "e2-micro" (dual vCPU) very small Ubuntu 24.04 VM on Google Cloud. I noticed that CPU usage peaks to 200% CPU for a split second at 10 min intervals, by the gce-workload... process. Also, every 10 minutes, I see messages like these
2024-07-16T10:28:04.206215+03:00 xxxsrv systemd[1]: Starting gce-workload-cert-refresh.service - GCE Workload Certificate refresh...
2024-07-16T10:28:04.226503+03:00 xxxsrv gce_workload_cert_refresh[48825]: 2024/07/16 10:28:04: Done
2024-07-16T10:28:04.229759+03:00 xxxsrv systemd[1]: gce-workload-cert-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-07-16T10:28:04.230374+03:00 xxxsrv systemd[1]: Finished gce-workload-cert-refresh.service - GCE Workload Certificate refresh.

in syslog.
I have found some information about gce-workload-cert-refresh.service at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/guest-agent
However, I need experienced opinions about it: Can I disable it? Or at least how can extend the refresh period from 10 minutes to something larger (to conserve CPU usage and syslog space)?

Presumably the people maintaining GCP are experienced enough on their own cloud and thought that having it enabled and running every 10 minutes is the best configuration? Why do you think it isn't? Have you raised a support ticket with them?

This is a e2-micro dual vCPU very small VM and I noticed that the CPU usage peaks to 200% CPU at 10 min intervals. @muru

Hmm, do you have security group rules blocking access that the service might require? Do you use workload identity for anything in this VM?
